# Console pane in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I want to add console pane to JavaFX app. I could use `TextArea` with `setEditable(false)`, but how can I set different colors to different messages (errors,warnings,info). I have experiense with Swing. So in Swing I was using `TextPane` inside of `ScrollPane` and `Style` for coloring. Has JavaFX an approach to do that? Which controls should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just displaying the text, you can use a `VBox` (for example) containing a collection of `Label`s or `Text`s, and then set the style on each one. If you are using Java 8, there's also a specialized [`TextFlow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) container available.

None of those will create text that can be selected and copied. If you need that functionality too, there's a third party library that will provide that: [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).